# format: "Error when reading /opt/ejabberd/.erlang.cookie: eacces"

Tags: erlang, distributed-computing, ejabberd, epmd

Ejabberd Clustering:

I have set up two Ejabberd servers in two different Digital Ocean Droplets.
And i am trying to build clustering on these two servers.
I followed the documentation in the Ejabberd official Docs i.e, 'https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/clustering/'

1. Copy the /home/ejabberd/.erlang.cookie file from ejabberd01 to ejabberd02.
2. Made sure my new ejabberd node is properly configured. My ejabberd.yml config file on the new node that on the other cluster nodes have same configs.
3. Then when i tried to start the clustering with the below command:
   $ ejabberdctl --no-timeout join_cluster 'ejabberd@ejabberd01'

I get the below Error:

```
args: []
format: "Error when reading /opt/ejabberd/.erlang.cookie: eacces"
label: {error_logger,error_msg}
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `eacess` thing in the error message is actually the `EACCESS` error return code [standardized by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_03.html#tag_02_03):

> [EACCES]
>   Permission denied.
>   An attempt was made to access a file in a way forbidden by its file access permissions.

In other words, the credentials which the Erlang BEAM process running your ejabberd node uses, are insufficient to open the Erlang cookie file `/opt/ejabberd/.erlang.cookie`.

You can start [here](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html#security) to get more background on what Erlang cookies are.

Comment: I have manually moved the file from one Digital ocean Server to another using :  scp user1@123.123:/var/www/file.sql /var/www/ command..How would i run the cluster by changing the file permission.